# How to improve my Generalized Additive Model (GAM) performance and fix heteroscedasticity?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, normal-distribution

I have a large datasets of data which I try to model with GAM. My model performance is otherwise good, but the errors are not normally distributed. Do you have any idea, how this problem could be solved? I have added the histogram of my data (skewness is 0.4 and thus, no transformation is needed), model results and the residual plots.

[image]

[image]

Code and model results for the model:

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x, k = 20) + s(z, k = 23) + w

Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   179.9106     0.2917   616.7   <2e-16 ***
w             -26.8263     0.2595  -103.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                    edf Ref.df       F p-value    
s(x)              15.33  16.44   611.9  <2e-16 ***
s(z)              16.39  18.53 24365.8  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.839   Deviance explained = 83.9%
-REML = 1.3054e+06  Scale est. = 1287.3    n = 261113
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried logging (can't tell: do you have zeros?) or square-rooting your y variable? PS: they're called Generalized Additive Models (not to be confused with Generative Adversarial Networks).

Comment: @JohnMadden Yes already tried logging and square-rooting. I don't have zeros in my data set.

Comment: What do the residuals look like when you do that?